# Cursor tracking is not immediately updated in the intersection window

Tags: ocean

I have implemented a toggle window that updates the **world cursor** on mouse move events with the following statement:

```
PetrelProject.ToggleWindows.WorldCursor.SetPosition(world, Domain.TVD_PRE, path.Trajectory);
```

The cursor is immediately updated in the 3D window, but the Intersection/Map window is not working properly. I have to force an update of the intersection window by manually moving the cursor outside my graphical canvas (ZedGraph). I can also force an update programmatically by the following statement in my mouse move event handler:

```
TopLevelControl.Refresh();
```

Unfortunately the latter is very performance costly and make the cursor tracking sluggish. To me it looks like a bug in `Petrel` (2016). Is there a better workaround for this then the one I am using?